# How to use take and with Laravel?

Tags: laravel

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Comment::class)
            ->orderBy("id", "desc")
            ->take(3);

Post::query()->with('comments')
             ->get;
```

How to fix it, what would work?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: In all models except the first one I get [ ]

Comment: `Post::query()->with(...)` is pointless; you can simply do `Post::with(...)->get();`. Won't fix your issue, but slightly more efficient.

Comment: Your two lines seem unrelated - if they're in the same function, the `return` will mean the second set of lines won't ever execute. You need `()` on your last line's `->get`. Your return probably needs a `get()` on the end after `take()`, too.

Comment: What do you need?

Comment: Are you just wanting to get the first 3 comments for each post? If so, it might be worth having a look at https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit#readme

Comment: Yes, get the first 3 comments for each post

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Comment::class);
```

and:

```
Post::with([
    'comments' => 
            function(Builder $query) { 
                    $query->orderBy("id", "desc")
                          ->take(3);
            }
    ])
    ->get();
```

So you can pass function in the `with` to `filter`, `order`, `take` or any other `Builder` methods to apply it on the specified relationship.

In general:

```
Model::with(['relationship' => function(Builder $query)
{
    // some code to filter, orderBy or take from relationship 
})->get()
```

Comment: In all models except the first one I get [ ]

Comment: Please double check your data, and post some samples with the output of my answer